# Apache Shiro JDBC Realm in an OSGi project

Tags: osgi, shiro, jdbcrealm

I'm trying to realize an authentication bundle in an OSGi project and I decided to use this powerful Apache Shiro framework. As I tried to initiate a JDBC realm using this shiro.ini file:

```
[main]

# Create JDBC realm.
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm

# Configure JDBC realm datasource.
dataSource = org.postgresql.Driver
dataSource.URL = jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/user
dataSource.user = postgres
dataSource.password = postgres
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource

# Configure JDBC realm SQL queries.
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM Users WHERE email = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role from roles WHERE id = (SELECT roleId FROM UserRoles WHERE userId = (SELECT id FROM Users WHERE email = ?))
```

I'm having this error message:

> Failed to start bundle
>   com.soner.prototype.auth.application.client-1.0.0.1, exception
>   activator error. Unable to instantiate class [org.postgresql.Driver]
>   for object named 'dataSource'.   Please ensure you've specified the
>   fully qualified class name correctly. from:
>   org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder:createNewInstance#309

I'm using PostgreSQL as it is seen in .ini file, and I have the PostegreSQL drivers bundle already loaded before activating Shiro bundle.

I think that I should have Shiro JDBC realm classes and they reside in Apache Shiro Core package which I import as a bundle. Does anyone have an idea or a workaround for this problem? Is Shiro available in OSGi environment only with its native .ini file realm?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the root cause? NoClassDef?

Comment: Nope, actually the only output I have is the error message that I shared in the question, and the obvious result that the realm wouldn't work.